# Hide datalist options if input field is blank

Tags: html, html-datalist

I have a simple datalist set up here. I want to prevent being able to click the input field to see the list of options before typing something in. I only want the list to show when some possible matches are available after typing something in.

```html
<input type="text" list="optionlist" autocomplete="off">
<datalist id="optionlist">
    <select>
            <option>Option 1</option>
            <option>Option 2</option>
            <option>Option 3</option>
            <option>Option 4</option>
            <option>Option 5</option>
    </select>
</datalist>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're using jQuery (or any element selection masking tool):

```
$("select").click(function (e) {
    if ($("[list=optionList]").val() == "") {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: I just [tested that](http://jsbin.com/motitapomi/edit?html,js,output), it does not have the behaviour the OP is asking for. When I click the input element, a drop-down menu appears showing all the options.